# ntheorem listtheorems creates duplicate entries

Tags: hyperref, ntheorem

I am using the package `ntheorem` for typesetting definitions and theorems. 
In the appendix I would like to have a list of all definitions/theoreoms including their names and page numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}[Foo]
foo foo foo
\end{definition}
\begin{definition}[Bar]
bar bar bar
\end{definition}
\theoremlisttype{allname}
\listtheorems{definition}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the output gets an extra extra line holding the term definition and its number.

[image]

I want to get rid of the lines `definition.1`,...

The problem seems to be the inclusion of the package `hyperref`. If I remove the package the definitions are listed properly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I have minimized your sample code. It didn't even load the `hyperref` package, so didn't show the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `hyperref` option of the `ntheorem` package

```
\usepackage[thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}
```

and the extra lines are gone (explained on page 4 of the user manual of the `ntheorem` package).

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I get the error :::: ** Generating table of definition
(./thesis.thm
! Undefined control sequence.
\thm@@thmline ...}#3}{#4} \else \ifHy@linktocpage 
                                                  \relax \relax \@dottedtocl...
l.2 \contentsline
                  {definition}{{Definition}{2}{Terms in STT}}{5}

Comment: This is the case when adding hyperref option regarless of the position of \include{hyperref} or whether it is actually in the document

Comment: @Waschbaer When I take the code that you originally posted, add the `hyperref` option when loading `ntheorem`, and add `\usepackage{hyperref}` immediately before `\begin{document}`, it works. The `hyperref` package has to be loaded last (with very few exceptions). If the problem remains, ask a new question, with the code that produces the error.